# What data entry system should I choose for multiple users at multiple sites?

Tags: ms-access, forms, webforms, data-entry

I've just started working on a project that will involve multiple people entering data from multiple geographic locations. I've been asked to prepare forms in Access 2003 to facilitate this data entry.  Right now, copies of the DB (with my tables and forms) will be distributed to each of the sites, returned to me, and then I get to hammer them all together. I can do that, but I'm hoping that there is a better way - if not for this project, then for future projects.

We don't have any funding for real programming support, so it's up to me. I am comfortable with HTML, CSS, and SQL,  have played around with Django a fair bit, and am a decently fast learner. I don't have much time to *design* forms, but they don't have to actually function for a few months.

I think there are some substantial benefits to web-based forms (primary keys are set centrally, I can monitor data entry, form changes are immediately and universally deployed, I don't have to do tech support for different versions of Access). But I'd love to hear from voices of experience about the actual benefits and hazards of this stuff.

This is very lightweight data entry - three forms attached to three tables, linked by person ID, certainly under 5000 total records.  While this is hardly bank account-type information, I do take the security of these data seriously, so that's an additional consideration. Any specific technology recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options that involve Access:

1. use Jet replication. If the machines where the data editing is being done can be connected via wired LAN to the central network, synchronization would be very easy to implement (via the simple Direct Synchronization, only a couple lines of code). If not (as seems the case), it's an order of magnitude more complex and requires significint setup of the remote systems. For an ongoing project, it can be a very good solution. For a one off, not so much. See the [Jet Replication Wiki](http://dfenton.com/DFA/Replication/) for lots of information on Jet Replication. One advantage of this solution is that it works completely offline (i.e., no Internet connection).
2. use Access for the front end and SQL Server (or some other server database) for the back end. Provide a mechanism for remote users to connect to the centrally-hosted database server, either over VPN (preferred) or by exposing a non-standard port to the open Internet (not recommended). For lightweight editing, this shouldn't require overmuch optimization of the Access app to get a usable application, but it isn't going to be as fast as a local connection, and how slow will depend on the users' Internet connections. This solution does require an Internet connection to be used.
3. host the Access app on a Windows Terminal Server. If the infrastructure is available and there's a budget for CALs (or if the CALs are already in place), this is a very, very easy way to share an Access app. Like #2, this requires an Internet connection, but it puts all the administration in one central location and requires no development beyond what's already been done to create the existing Access app.

For non-Access solutions, it's a matter of building a web front end. For the size app you've outlined, that sounds pretty simple for the person who already knows how to do that, not so much for the person who doesn't!

Even though I'm an Access developer, based on what you've outlined, I'd probably recommend a light-weight web-based front end, as simple as possible with no bells and whistles. I use PHP, but obviously any web scripting environment would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David: a web-based solution sounds the most suitable.

I use CodeCharge Studio for that: it has a very Access-like interface, lots of wizards to create online forms etc. CCS offers a number of different programming languages; I use PHP, as part of a LAMP stack.